# How do you see all merge requests where you are an approver in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I'd like to see all the pending merge requests where I am listed as an approver. How do I find them? Currently, I can only see how to filter for merge requests by assignee or author, not approver. Outside of e-mail, how do you figure out which merge requests you need to respond to and review?

Comment: Can't you see them on the TODO list? Can't test it right now but I think you get notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't.

However, there is [work in progress to be able to list MRs by approver](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1951).

Answer (score 0):

As of version 13.9, you can [filter the merge request list with "Approved-by"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/#filter-the-list-of-merge-requests). It's also something you can [filter by in the API list of merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html).

However, it's a paid feature, so a subscription is required.